# Moq TestMethod C#ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I study to write a module test by moq , and this simply test failed with

> Message: Test method UnitTests.AdminTests.IndexContainPlayerList threw
>   exception: System.NullReferenceException:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void IndexContainPlayerList()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IPlayerRepository> mock = new Mock<IPlayerRepository>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Players).Returns(new List<Player>() {
            new Player () { Id = 1, Name = "Karye", Surname = "Irving", Team = new Team(){ Id = 1, Name = "Boston Celtics" }, TeamId = 1 },
            new Player () { Id = 1, Name = "Stephan", Surname = "Carry", Team = new Team(){ Id = 2, Name = "Golden State Warriors" }, TeamId = 2 }
        });

        AdminController target = new AdminController(mock.Object, null);

        //Action
        Player[] resultList = ((IEnumerable<Player>)target.Index().ViewData.Model).ToArray();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(resultList.Length, 2);
    }
```

method which I am testing

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ChoosingTeam = new SelectList(teamRepository.Teams, "Name ", "Name");
        return View(playerRepository.Players.ToList());
    }
```

why test run failed, may be i lose something or don't understand?

Comment: In the exception stacktrace, it should give you a hint to what line the NRE is being thrown.

Comment: ViewBag.ChoosingTeam = ....;
but it need to realize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullReferenceException` is being thrown is because you are passing a `null` into your `AdminController` that I am *assuming* is for your `ITeamsRepository`.

As you can see you are attempting to access the `teamRepository`, since that is null, a `NullReferenceException` is being thrown.

You need to also mock out that dependency.
Example:

```
Mock<ITeamsRepository> teamsMock = new Mock<ITeamsRepository>();
AdminController target = new AdminController(mock.Object, teamsMock.Object);
```

Comment: @Andrei Excellent, I would also question the point of that test, it's not really testing anything other than verifying that it's using your `IPlayerRepository` to get players.

Comment: i check, sent Index() method the model <Player> to View, and check those or not those Players are sending to view